# Test if two IDictionary objects contain the same values

Tags: c#, unit-testing, hash-map

I'm adding a function to my test library to assist in testing if two `IDictionary` objects contain the same keys/values.

I need the method to be generic and support a dictionary that has collections as values. So I thought I'd try to do it without using class types.

It *appears* to be working, but I would like to clarify that I didn't make any mistakes that would impact my tests later.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if two dictionaries contain the same values. Supports recursive
    /// dictionaries and collections as values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pExpect">Expected value</param>
    /// <param name="pActual">Actual value</param>
    // ReSharper disable CanBeReplacedWithTryCastAndCheckForNull
    public static void dictionary(IDictionary pExpect, IDictionary pActual)
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(pExpect);
        Assert.IsNotNull(pActual);

        if (pExpect.Keys.Count != pActual.Keys.Count)
        {
            Assert.Fail("Expected {0} keys, but contains {1} keys.", pExpect.Keys.Count, pActual.Keys.Count);
        }

        object[] expectKeys = new object[pExpect.Keys.Count];
        object[] actualKeys = new object[pExpect.Keys.Count];

        pExpect.Keys.CopyTo(expectKeys, 0);
        pActual.Keys.CopyTo(actualKeys, 0);

        // check if the two key sets are the same
        CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expectKeys, actualKeys);

        for (int i = 0, c = expectKeys.Length; i < c; i++)
        {
            object expect = pExpect[expectKeys[i]];
            object actual = pActual[actualKeys[i]];

            // both can be null
            if (expect == null && actual == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // both must be assigned a value
            Assert.IsNotNull(expect);
            Assert.IsNotNull(actual);

            // must be same types
            Assert.AreEqual(expect.GetType(), actual.GetType());

            if (expect is IDictionary)
            {
                // support recursive dictionary checks
                dictionary((IDictionary)expect, (IDictionary)actual);
            }
            else if (expect is ICollection)
            {
                CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent((ICollection)expect, (ICollection)actual);
            }
            else
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(expect, actual);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am wondering if my last check `Assert.AreEqual(expect, actual)` will cover most remaining test cases.

**EDIT:** Fixed testing dictionaries that have keys in different orders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't work, because items in a dictionary aren't ordered in any way.

Example code that fails your test:

```
dictionary(
    new Dictionary<int, int> { { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 } },
    new Dictionary<int, int> { { 1, 1 }, { 0, 0 } });
```

Some more notes about your code:

```
public static void dictionary(IDictionary pExpect, IDictionary pActual)
```

`dictionary` is a bad name for this method, because it doesn't really explain what it's supposed to do. Something like `DictionaryEqualityTest` would be better.

Also, I would avoid using the non-generic `IDictionary` if possible, `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` would be better (though it would complicate the recursion).

Comment: thanks for the fail. I'll see if I can fix it. I know the name is weak, but it's in a class called "Same" which does nothing but same checks.

Comment: I fixed the problem and updated the question. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You could get an endless recursion with the following code:

```
var dict1 = new Hashtable(); 
var dict2 = new Hashtable();
dict1.Add(1,dict1);
dict2.Add(1,dict2);
dictionary(dict1,dict2);
```